# PHP operator to see if something has part of something

Tags: php, preg-match

I currently have a problem. I have a code that looks like the one below and I want an operator that checks if a part of a query is present in an array. This is the code that I have:

```
<?php
$search = 'party hat';
$query = ucwords($search);
$string = file_get_contents('http://clubpenguincheatsnow.com/tools/newitemdatabase/items.php');
$string = explode('<br>',$string);
foreach($string as $row)
{
    preg_match('/^(\D+)\s=\s(\d+)\s=\s(\D+)\s=\s(\d+)/', trim($row), $matches);
    if($matches[1] == "$query")
    {
        echo "<a href='http://clubpenguincheatsnow.com/tools/newitemdatabase/info.php?id=$matches[2]'>";
        echo $matches[1];
        echo "</a><br>";
    }
}
?>
```

What I want to do is instead of `if($matches[1] == "$query")` to check if both are identical, I want my code to see if a PART of `$query` exists in `$matches[1]`. How do I do this though? Please help me!

Comment: You need to be a little more specific: every string has a part that exists in every other string. For example the empty string between the two Xs in `XX` can be found before the `A` in `ABC`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos) to test if a string is contained in another string:

```
if(strpos($matches[1], $query) !== false)
```

If you prefer it to be case insensitive, use [`stripos`](http://php.net/stripos) instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if $query is a substring of $matches[1], you can use

`strpos($matches[1], $query) !== false`

(see documentation for why you must use !==).

Answer (score 0):

You can use strstr to test if a string contains another string:

```
if(strstr($matches[1], $query)) {
    // do something ...
}
```